# Does the derivative of $\;\sqrt{x}- \arctan \sqrt{x} \;$ exist at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

This is an exercise in Apostol Calculus Vol.1 E6.22 Q.16.

Let $\,f(x)=\sqrt{x} - \arctan \sqrt{x}.\;$ Then

$$\begin{align} f'(x) &= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}- \frac{1}{1+(\sqrt{x})^2} \frac{1} 
{2\sqrt{x}}
\\&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \frac {1+x-1}{1+x}
\\&= \frac {1} {2\sqrt{x}} \frac{x}{1+x}
\\&= \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2(1+x)}
\end{align}$$

The answer from the textbook said it's valid if $x\geq0$, but we cancel out $\sqrt{x}$ when deriving $f'(x)$.

I don't know why it's valid when $x=0$, so I hope someone could give me an explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: **Does** the derivative of $\sqrt{x}- \arctan \sqrt{x}$  **exist** at $x=0$?

Comment: oops,thanks for correcting my typo.

Comment: Please use `\arctan`.

Comment: This is a great question (+1), and regarding the validity, is $x=0$ in the domain of the given function? Because if it is, then your derivative gives the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computation of $f'(0)$ requires a separate argument, namely the fact that
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{x}-\arctan\sqrt{x}\sim\frac13x\sqrt{x},
$$
when $x\to0$, hence, using $f(0)=0$,
$$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac13\sqrt{x}=0.
$$

Comment: wow,you're really fast.How did you get $ \frac{1}{3} x \sqrt{x}$ from $\sqrt{x} - \arctan \sqrt{x} $?

Comment: $\arctan(t)=t-\frac13t^3+O(t^5)$.

Comment: Oh,it's the content of the next chapter of my textbook.Thanks.